# A special graph coloring problem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, directed-graphs

> Let $G$ be an undirected graph. We define:
>
> An ***Orientation*** $D$ from $G$: A subgraph $D$ with $V(D) = V(G)$ such that for every edge $\{u, v\} \in E(G)$, we take either $(u, v)$ or $(v, u)$ in $D$.
>
> We call a function $c: V(D) \rightarrow \{1, ..., k\}$ a $k$-***In-Out-Coloring*** if for every vertex $v \in V(D)$ the following holds:
> $$\{c(u) | (u, v) \in E(D) \} \cap \{c(w) | (v, w) \in E(D) \} = \phi$$
>
> In other words, no vertex in a $k$-in-out-colored, directed graph has an in-neighbor $u$ and an out-neighbor $w$, so that $c(u) = c(w)$. In this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Svs.png) for example, the vertices $0$, and $2$ have to colored in different colors, so $c(0) \neq c(2)$. Note that we didn't impose restrictions on vertex $1$, it is allowed to be colored in $c(0)$ or $c(2)$.
>
> For a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and a subset $C \subseteq A$ we define a **restriction** from $f$ onto $C$ as $f_{\restriction C}(x):= f(x)$ if $x \in C$. So the function $f_{\restriction C}$ has the type $f_{\restriction C}: C \rightarrow B.$
>
> Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed, $G$ an undirected Graph (with no parallel edges or self-loops) with countably infinite vertices and let $c:V(G) \rightarrow \{1, ..., k\}$ be an $k$-in-out coloring function.
>
> Prove: If every finite subgraph $G'$ from $G$ has an orientation which is $k$-in-out-colored by $c_{\restriction V}(G')$, then there must exist an orientation of $G$, which is $k$-in-out-colored by $c$.

There are too many layers in this proof and I don't know where to begin. A proof by contradiction seems suitable but even then, I don't see what follows.

If every subgraph $G'$ has an orientation which is $k$-in-out-colorable by $c_{\restriction V}(G')$, then the subgraph $H$ with $V(H) = V(G)$ and $E(H) = E(G)$ is $k$-in-out-colorable by $c_{\restriction V}(G')$. If $H$ is $k$-in-out-colorable by this restriction function, then it must be colorable by $c$, and so must be $G$, which is exactly the same graph as $H$. So I'm not really sure what the question is looking for. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you’re supposed to consider the case where G has infinitely many vertices.

Comment: You write"let $c::V(G)\to\{1,\dots,k\}$ be a $k$-in-out coloring function" but it's not clear what "$k$-in-out coloring function" means, seeing as $G$ is an undirected graph. I think you (or the person you're quoting) meant to write "let $c:V(G)\to\{1,\dots,k\}$ be a function."

Answer (score 2):

As the vertex set is enumerable, so does the set of edges. Let $\{e_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $E(G)$. For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, let $e_{i}=\{u_{i},v_{i}\}$ and define $$G_{i} = \left(\{u_1,v_1,\ldots,v_i,u_i\}\bigcup_{j = 1}^i e_{i},  \{ e_{j} ~\colon j \in \{1,\ldots, i\}\})\right).$$ In other words, $G_{i}$ is the finite graph induced by the edges $\{e_{1},\ldots, e_{i}\}$. Let $G_{i}'$ be the orientation of $G_{i}$ having a $k$-in-out-coloring.

We define an orientation in $\{e_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ by induction. First, we have two ways to orientate the edge $e_{1}$, $(u_{1},v_{1})$ or $(v_{1},u_{1})$. As we have two orientations of $e_1$ appearing in an infinity number of digraphs $G_i'$, then, by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), at least one of theses orientations occurs in an infinite subsequence of $\{G_{i}'\}$. We define $\overrightarrow{e_{1}}$ to be a orientation of $e_{1}$ occurring in a infinity number of the orientations $\{G_{i}'\}$; let $\{G_{i_{k}}'\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the subsequence where such orientation occurss. Now, using the argument, notice that some orientation of $e_{2}$ occurs in an infinite number of orientations of $\{G_{i_{k}}\}$. Then, taking a subsequence of $\{G_{i_{k}}\}$, we find infinitely many indexes $j_1,j_2,\ldots$, such that in all digraphs $\{G_{j_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, the orientation of $e_1$ is $\overrightarrow{e_{1}}$, and the orientation of $e_2$ is fixed as well, denote it by $\overrightarrow{e_{2}}$.

In this way, for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we can define a orientation $\overrightarrow{e_{i}}$. Then, $A=\{\overrightarrow{e_{1}},\overrightarrow{e_{2}},\ldots\}$ is a orientation of $G$.

We must prove that $A$ respects the property, i.e., for the coloring given in hypothesis, every direct path $(w_1,z,w_2)$ is such that $c(w_1)\neq c(w_2)$. Suppose otherwise, take two vertices $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ such that $c(w_{1}) = c(w_{2})$ and  $(w_1,z,w_2)$ is a directed path in $(V(G),A)$. Let $i_{1}$ and $i_{2}$ be natural numbers such that $(w_{1}, z) = \overrightarrow{e_{i_1}}$ and $(z,w_{2}) = \overrightarrow{e_{i_{2}}}$. Without loss of generality suppose that $i_{2} > i_{1}$.

Using our construction, we know that there is a subsequence $\{G_{j_k}'\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ where the orientations of $e_1,\ldots,e_{i_2}$ are constant and equal to $\overrightarrow{e_{1}},\ldots,\overrightarrow{e_{i_2}}$. Let $G^*$ be an arbitrary graph in this subsequence of orientations. As $(w_{1},z,w_{2})$ is a directed path in $G^*$ and the property holds in the finite case(by hypothesis), we have that $c(w_{1}) \neq c(w_{2})$. A contradiction.

I know that it is far from being easy to understand this demonstration and maybe its because of my english mistakes, I am sorry in advance. If you don't understand, feel free to ask.

Comment: I think this could also be presented as an application of Kőnig's Infinity Lemma. More generally, the result can be proved without the countability assumption using an ultrafilter, or using the compactness of the space of orientations of $G$ considered as a Tychonoff product of $2$-point spaces.